# TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

Tags: string, int

i am trying to learn python language (v3 above) for myself, and im stuck at the early stages!

This exercise was taken from a python exercise website and their solutions go through the same conclusion that i reached still no good. I have this very basic code:

```
numero = input("introduza um numero:")

print ("O numero é:", numero)

print ("O resultado é:")

print (((numero + 3) * 2) - 4 - (2 * numero) + 3)**
```

Thing is i did search in stackoverflow for this matter, but it happens that i only find extensive code lines of this error and i get lost.

The program runs until i input the number then i get this:

> TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly

It happens everytime i have a input command before any declaring variable or print command.

Thanks for the atention!

Comment: Well, what is the error message telling you? It won't convert an integer to string for you. So... the conclusion is... you should do it yourself maybe? How would you do that? Using `str()` somehow?

Comment: Since "numero" came from input, it's a string. So "numero + 3" is meaningless. Either convert it to an int, or convert the 3 to a string.

Comment: A whole mess for something so simple thank guys

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3, `input` returns a `string` containing the user's input.

So, a possible value for `numero` would be `"3"`. Python is telling you that you can't do math on `string`s and `int`s together.

You could change your first line to something like this:

```
numero = int(input("introduza um numero:"))
```

This converts the user's input into an `int`, throwing an error if their input cannot be converted.

Comment: ahhh thanks alot, i did put int before int it, but never worked happens to be i forgot to close  the ( for the int command the int.

Answer (score 0):

`input` taking data as string, you have to convert it to integer if you want to do some math calculates.

```
numero = int(input("introduza um numero:"))
```

This will convert your `numero` to an integer, then you can do calculates. Remember;

```
"4" != 4
```

First one is a `string`, second one is an `integer`. An example;

```
numero = int(input("introduza um numero:"))
print (((numero + 3) * 2) - 4 - (2 * numero) + 3)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but happened to be more simple than. I  have to close the gap when i introduced int, wasn't paying atention.

Comment: i didn't closed the whole command when i put int. Sorry english not my main language

Comment: @NunoCorreia I edited my answer check the example please. Copy-paste it to your script.

Comment: `numero = int(input("introduza um numero:"))` i was missing the last `)` closed it i had it like this: `numero = int(input("introduza um numero:")`